# Entity Framework 7 Lambda expression for 3 table joins

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to built an API that will return all the data for a server. A server can have multiple endpoints and they are stored in separate table with many-to-many relationship.

I have 3 tables:

- `Servers` table contains all the server details
- `Applications` table that contains application names
- `application_endpoint` table that contains foreign keys to both tables `Servers` and `Applications`

Here is my database model:

[image]

Here are my models:

```
public class Servers
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string server_name { get; set; }
        public string alias { get; set; }
        public string ip_address { get; set; }
        public Status status { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Application_endpoints> endpoint { get; set; }
}

public class Application_endpoints
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int? server_id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("server_id")]
        public Servers server { get; set; }
        public int? application_id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("application_id")]
        public Applications application { get; set; }
}

public class Applications
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string app_name { get; set; }
}

public class ServerDbContext : DbContext
{
        public DbSet<Applications> Applications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Application_endpoints> Application_endpoints { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Servers> Servers { get; set; }
}
```

In my Api Controller, I have created `HttpGet` method that will query database and return data for each server. Here is simple API for GET:

```
private ServerDbContext _context;

public ServersController (ServerDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

// GET: api/values
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get()
{
    var servers = _context.Servers
        .Include(endpoint => endpoint.endpoint)
        .ToList();
    return Json(servers);
}
```

Now when I make a get request, I get data back from the database, however the `application` object in below JSON is returned null. I am trying to figure it out how to add left join in my above query so I can get application name from applications table.

```
{
  "id": 6,
  "server_name": "server1",
  "alias": "",
  "ip_address": "192.168.1.7",
  "endpoint": [
    {
      "id": 23,
      "server_id": 6,
      "application_id": 10,
      "application": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help is really appreciated. :)

Comment: Have you tried '.Include(endpoint => endpoint.endpoint.Select(e=> e.application))'? For what i rember this is how you do it in EF6

Answer (score 2):

To all,

Thank you for guiding me to right path. I did quick google search and it appears that syntax has changed in EF7. Below worked for me :)

```
var servers = _context.Servers
            .Include(e => e.endpoint).ThenInclude(a => a.application)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your include in your query:

from

```
   .Include(endpoint => endpoint.endpoint)
```

to

```
    .Include(s => s.endpoint.Select(e => e.application))
```

Or you can use string path as

```
    .Include("endpoint.application")
```

Comment: Vittore and omar.ballerani, I just tried your suggestion, however, I get an exception when I make a get request. Here is the exception: `Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Remotion.Linq.Clauses.Expressions.SubQueryExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'.`

Comment: @vittore - The above query throws an exception in my case "make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion". I have shown the db diagram and the complete query here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453123/get-selected-values-after-joining-multiple-tables-in-entity-framework-6-using-la Could you please have a look at!?